# Display a linked text instead of displaying an Url in Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, hyperlink

I am importing data some from excel in Woocommerce.

The below code is displaying an URL on a webpage. Instead I would like to convert it as an hyperlink with the text "Click here".

```
<td>'.__('Montagevejledning', 'wtf').'</td>
<td>'.$data[41].'</td>
```

What do I need to change in my code?

Comment: Please kindly see the [tour] and [ask] page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following instead, that should display a linked 'Click here' *(as a self opening link)*:

```
<td>'.__('Montagevejledning', 'wtf').'</td>
<td><a href="'.$data[41].'" target="_blank">'.__('Click here', 'wtf').'</a></td>
```

It should work as you expect.

Comment: awesome thanks it works what if i want to have it that it opens another tab instead of the same tab?

Comment: @bilkrogbilkrog I have updated the answer code…

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot - I was trying to do this for half of the day